# Resize method is not implemented Python

Tags: python, image-segmentation

Hi I am working on a project to do segmentation for persons. Now I followed the code from https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Image_pascal.html#image-pascal and it is giving me an error: **ValueError: Resize method is not implemented.** in line 4.

```
import pixellib
from pixellib.semantic import semantic_segmentation

segment_video = semantic_segmentation()
segment_video.load_pascalvoc_model("deeplabv3_xception_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
segment_video.process_video_pascalvoc("IMG_2649.mp4",  overlay = True, frames_per_second= 15, 
output_video_name="output.mp4")
```

Anyone know why this error is being triggered?

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Yolo/person_seg.py", line 4, in <module>
    segment_video = semantic_segmentation()
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\pixellib\semantic.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.model = Deeplab_xcep_pascal()
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\pixellib\deeplab.py", line 214, in Deeplab_xcep_pascal
    method='bilinear', align_corners=True))(b4)
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 554, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 743, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\pixellib\deeplab.py", line 214, in <lambda>
    method='bilinear', align_corners=True))(b4)
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 960, in resize_images
    name=None)
  File "G:\anaconda3\envs\yolo5\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\image_ops_impl.py", line 1088, in resize_images_v2
    raise ValueError('Resize method is not implemented.')
ValueError: Resize method is not implemented.
```

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) prior installing the library (installed the latest version of tensorflow >2.0.0, imgaug and issuing: pip3 install pixellib --upgrade) ? Seems like an issue with the specific version of tensorflow installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks :). My Tensorflow Version was 1.13.1

Comment: I'll post the answer for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to follow the [initial steps](https://pixellib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) prior installing the PixelLib library, since it requires the latest version of Tensorflow (Tensorflow 2.0+) as well as imgaug.